# Iptables is blocking postfix when sending an email

Tags: email, postfix, iptables

My iptables is causing postfix server not to send emails.

A problematic mail.log line is:

> Mar  1 06:19:44 server postfix/smtp[9744]: 3D62CA06CA9:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=42, delays=2.3/0.01/40/0,
>   dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name
>   service error for name=gmail.com type=MX: Host not found, try again)

I found the other guy's [explanation on how to fix this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-iptables-12-how-to-block-or-open-dnsbind-service-port-53.html).

He proposed:

```
SERVER_IP="202.54.10.20"
DNS_SERVER="202.54.1.5 202.54.1.6"
for ip in $DNS_SERVER
do
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s $SERVER_IP --sport 1024:65535 -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp -s $ip --sport 53 -d $SERVER_IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT-p tcp -s $SERVER_IP --sport 1024:65535 -d $ip --dport 53 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s $ip --sport 53 -d $SERVER_IP --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
done
```

Isn't there any simpler rule without using the IP?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firewall paranoia doesn't really work if you don't even understand your firewall.

Just set the OUTPUT policy to ACCEPT and allow ESTABLISHED traffic back in.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED and since my OUTPUT policy is ACCEPT so everything now works.